# add generics on an interface property only and not on the interface

Tags: c#, generics

i created an interface which will serve as a datatype for some set of objects, when defining those object the datatype of one of their properties are unknown, thus why i need an interface. but .net wouldnt let me do this;

```
 public interface IClipbaseData 
{
    T ClipObjectData<T> { get; set;} 

}

 class ClipTextData : IClipbaseData
{

    string _clipContent;
    public string ClipObjectData 
    {
        get
        {
            return _clipContent;
        }
        set
        {
            // validate the input
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Error");
            }
            _clipContent = value;
        }
    }



}
```

i am getting an error on the interface, unexpected use of generic name. i know i could declare the generic on the interface but i dont want to because i am not aware of the generic datatype when using the interface as an object type.

but i am aware of the property datatype when creating classes to implement this interface

i can as well declare the property as object in the interface and dont use generics, but why am i unable to use generics

- a typical scenario why i dont want to add the generics on the interface:

an object is defined of IClipbaseData, this object can be of any concrete class that implements IClipbaseData. the concrete class which it belongs to can only be determined at runtime, thus we dont know the datatype of the property ClipObjectData before runtime

Comment: You'll have to make it a type parameter on the interface itself.

Comment: Make it a method instead of a property. A generic property requires the Type be known at instantiation.

Comment: If you don't know the type until runtime, how can you expect to pass it to `string.IsNullOrEmpty`?

Comment: you are specifying the return type as string, so you know the datatype to be used

Comment: Really old post, but it's probably still relevant: http://secondboyet.com/Articles/GenericProperties.html

Comment: @Lee i know the data type when declaring the property in a concrete class, however more than one concrete class can implement this interface, therefore the interface isn't aware what the concrete classes will be defining this property data type as

Comment: What do you mean by the interface 'being aware' of the property type? It sounds like you want `public interface IClipbaseData<T>` from your description but you've ruled this out. Could you add an example of why this won't work to your question?

Comment: @Lee i never mentioned the interface "being aware" of the property type. a typical example is defining an object of IClipbaseData, based on my code logic, this object can be of any concrete class that implements IClipbaseData. the concrete class which it belongs to can only be determined at runtime, thus we dont know the datatype of the property before runtime

Comment: @TobiOwolawi - "therefore the interface isn't aware what the concrete classes will be defining this property data type as". What interface are you referring to here? It sounds like you have a collection of implementations which use a different `T`? Or are you creating the instances dynamically in some way? What is the logic that prevents you knowing statically what the property type is?

Comment: @Lee the interfaces are created dynamically from an external source of data, this data can be of any of the object types i have a concrete class created for which implements the interface IClipbaseData

Answer (score 0):

Properties can't accept type parameters like that, you can define the type parameter on the interface itself, which will make your type work. This is one case where if you want to use a generic type parameter for a property, you must define it on the interface itself.

```
public interface IClipbaseData<T>
{
    T ClipObjectData { get; set; }
}

class ClipTextData : IClipbaseData<string>
{

    string _clipContent;
    public string ClipObjectData
    {
        get
        {
            return _clipContent;
        }
        set
        {
            // validate the input
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Error");
            }
            _clipContent = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise you would have to call properties like `var someValue = clipTextDataObj.ClipObjectData<string>;`, which really doesn't make a lot of sense to do it that way since the concrete type already defines what it returns.

If you do not want to define it on your interface, you'll have to create separate getter/setter methods:

```
public interface IClipbaseData
{
    T GetClipObjectData<T>();
    void SetClipObjectData<T>(T value);
}
```

But this would require you to implement it in a generic way:

```
class ClipTextData : IClipbaseData
{
    public T GetClipObjectData<T>()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void SetClipObjectData<T>(T value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But you could add yet another abstraction here:

```
class StringClipTextData : ClipTextData
{
    public string ClipObjectData
    {
        get { return base.GetClipObjectData<string>(); }
        set { base.SetClipObjectData(value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP already knows this. They don’t know the type at instantiation though.

Comment: @maccettura Right, but it isn't possible to define a property that way, I clarified how to do it with separate methods.

Comment: For completeness, would you just have a `private object data;` and then `GetClipObjectData` would `return data as T;`, and `SetClipObjectData` would do `data = value;`?

Comment: @RufusL Are you asking me to add code? I left it blank because it wasn't really relevant to what the question is about, but I could add it in.

Comment: No, I was just thinking out loud about how it would be implemented. :)